# Spring boot 2 - Unable to register and use JNDI in embedded tomcat container

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am using spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and trying to register a JNDI in embedded tomcat container.
Below is my spring boot starter class-

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ContextResource;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {

@Override
protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
tomcat.enableNaming();
return new TomcatWebServer(tomcat, getPort() >= 0);
}

@Override
protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
resource.setName("java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDSNonXA");
resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
resource.setProperty("url", "DBURL");
resource.setProperty("username", "DBUSER");
resource.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD");
context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
}
};
}
}
```

My spring configuration class is as follows-

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/hibernate-settings.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

/*Logic to load values from property file here*/

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myentityManagerFactory(DataSource mydataSource) {
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
emf.setDataSource(mydataSource);
emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
emf.setPersistenceUnitName("mydbunit");

Properties jpaProperties= new Properties();
jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialectValue);
jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", trxManagerLookupClass);
jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", generateStatistics);
jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", showSql);
jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", formatSql);
emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
emf.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
return emf;
}



@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException,
            NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDSNonXA");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }


@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}

}
```

I am primarily getting the exception-
Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/OracleDSNonXA] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Below is detailed exception trace.

```
   2018-03-16 13:22:59.450  WARN 4892 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myentityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/alj/mypage/config/ApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mydbunit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    2018-03-16 13:22:59.452  INFO 4892 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2018-03-16 13:22:59.468  INFO 4892 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-03-16 13:22:59.474 ERROR 4892 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myentityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/alj/mypage/config/ApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mydbunit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.alj.mypage.config.MySpringBootApplication.main(MySpringBootApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mydbunit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
```

I am very new to Spring boot and I am not sure what configuration I have missed.

Comment: Why? You are using an embedded container why bother with JNDI? Just use a regular configured `Datasource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I also require the use of JNDI with embedded tomcat because I'm planning to use spring config server and jndi datasource while deployment of wars. When testing locally, I wouln't want to comment jndi datasource code and use spring datsource. In that case, I would preferably want to use jndi with embedded tomcat which will be loaded on say 'dev' profile and the jndi name would be read from config server and use the external container specific jndi datasource when changing profile to say 'uat' or 'prod'.

Comment: You shouldn't comment anything. Just use a different configuration without JNDI for your testing... Just supply a different config for the test profile.

Comment: Good question!  --- I'm looking to find the same solution.  The idea is to continue using existing JNDI datasource names (there are multiple in this app)  and - as much as possible - leave the existing code base (formerly deployed to a jee app server)  that utilizes the JNDI datasources in tact.